# regex for this query

Tags: java, regex

I would like to see if a `.` exists in a string followed by a number

```
E.g 123.456 = True
E.g 123456. = False
E.g 123456 = False
E.g 123.456. = True
```

Any Regex genius out there?

Comment: this is a very basic regex, you do not need a genius, even i can answer.

Comment: the question is easy if you know the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\.(?=[0-9])
```

matches a dot iff it's followed by a digit. In Java, that is

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\.(?=[0-9])");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
foundMatch = regexMatcher.find();
```

Comment: How does this compare to `\.\d`?

Comment: Your regex also matches the digit, mine only matches the dot (if it's followed by a digit). The OP's question is a bit vague on whether he wants the digit to be part of the match. It probably doesn't matter...

Comment: sorry, but still cannot understand. could you please explain what does that '?=' mean?

Comment: thanks a million. im very new to java . To clarify solution i done the following which works. import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern; Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\.(?=[0-9])");
   Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(currentNumber);
   boolean foundMatch = regexMatcher.find();
   
   
   
   if (foundMatch) {
      // do nothing as decimal point already exists
    }
   else
   {
    decimalPointActive = true;
   }

Answer (score 2):

Regex would be `'\\.\\d'` I believe

Comment: Don't forget to escape the backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
String regex="\\.\\d";
```